# Can't paste text into Google Docs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google

I use Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I am unable to paste in Google Docs. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-V doesn't work. I can paste in a comment on google doc, but not in the main document.

I am not sure if it related, but when I paste in facebook, the comment boxes just disappear. I have to refresh the page for them to return. If I type one character before I paste, it works.

I have a second laptop that runs Ubuntu. Firefox is synced with that one. I can paste on that laptop.

That laptop runs firefox 57.03 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I have the same behavior in google docs and Firefox v64.0 (64-bit), Ubuntu 18.04.1 (actually Kubuntu/KDE) -- no comment wrt facebook issues. Can't paste at all into google docs, but I can into google docs comments. Works fine on Chrome on the same laptop.

Answer (score 9):

Just to note, for me such a problem was caused/solved by the privacy setting `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`.

When I opened Firefox about:config and set dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled to true, the Google Docs clipboard functionality started working.

Comment: This should be a comment, but because Stack is broken (IMHO), I'll have to post it as an answer... Can `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` be set per domain? I have more trust in google.com than the combined internet.

Answer (score 0):

The inability to paste into Google Docs in some versions of Firefox and other browsers is a [known issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196485). The problem is explained in [this article](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2014/04/13/copy-and-paste-in-google-docs/7568661/). Basically, it's a security feature blocking code from accessing your clipboard (which, if you think about it, might contain passwords and other sensitive information):

> it's the inevitable outcome of two things intersecting; interactive sites that use Web code ([...] JavaScript) to look and act like programs installed directly on your computer, and a standard security precaution in browsers that blocks Web code from any access to the system clipboard.
>
> Why lock them out? [Because y]our computer can't tell the difference between a JavaScript-driven action that you took, such as clicking a button in a Web app, and one that a website executed on its own and without your consent. And it's a lot easier to find yourself on a malicious website than to install malicious software.

My workaround for this is to import text from a document on my system. This is even possible in spreadsheets (select **Replace data at selected cell** from the import menu).

If you want to be able to use keyboard shortcuts as normal, you can use Google Chrome browser, which accepts some code when you log in to Google Docs that allows access to the clipboard. Apparently, Google just can't manage to maintain full support for every version of every browser...